# Trying to output number of occurances of * in a string

Tags: java

This is doing my head in. I am trying to count the number of *'s that occur in user input, taken from the input Scanner. But every time I try, it either keeps adding the numbers from previous lines, or refuses to output anything. Feeling lost and frustrated because I can't see any problem with the code. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong.
Compiler is giving no syntax errors, and I can't see the logic error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lab11{

public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;
        input = kb.nextLine();
        int count = 0;
        while(!input.equals("#")){
                input = kb.nextLine();
                for(count = 1; count < input.length(); count ++){
                        int starCount = 0;
                        if(input.charAt(count)=='*'){
                                starCount++;

                        }//if
                        System.out.println(starCount);
                }//for
        }//while


}//main

}//class
```

Comment: Try if String.indexOf is greater than -1 for the index of the char and then continue from its substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing `starCount` inside the for loop so it gets `0` after every iteration.
And also your `count` should start from `0`& your `System.out.println(starCount);` statement should be after for loop coz you have to print the final value of `starCount` once for every user input.

Modify your code like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input="";
            int count = 0;
            while(true){
                    input = kb.nextLine();
                    if(input.equals("#"))
                        break;

                    int starCount=0;
                    for(count = 0; count < input.length(); count ++){
                            if(input.charAt(count)=='*'){
                                    starCount++;
                            }//if
                    }//for
                    System.out.println(starCount);
            }//while
        }//main
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Rajeev

Answer (score 0):

Seems problem with your `while loop` and `input = kb.nextLine();` in while loop.

If you simply need to get count of `'*'` in the string,then below should work for you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;
        input = kb.nextLine();
        int count = 0;
        int starCount = 0;
        for (count = 0; count < input.length(); count++) {
            if (input.charAt(count) == '*') {
                starCount++;

            }//if
        }//for
        System.out.println(starCount);


    }//main
```

Answer (score 0):

You should/can do something like this:

```
String input = "abc*defde *d z*dz *";

final long count = input.chars( )
                        .filter( c -> c == '*' )
                        .count( );
```

It is a one-liner on Java 8 using the Stream API

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems in your code 1) you are replacing the first line from user input with the second line. So first line will never be considered. 2) the variable inside for loop get initialized in each loop iteration. SO it will count 1 if current char is * else 0. 3) start loop with count value as 0 not 1. Try below code

```
public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input;
            input = kb.nextLine();
            int count = 0;
            while(!input.equals("#")){
                int starCount = 0;
                    for(count = 0; count < input.length(); count ++){
                            if(input.charAt(count)=='*'){
                                    starCount++;

                            }//if
                    }//for
                    System.out.println(starCount);
                    input = kb.nextLine();
            }//while


    }//main
```

Answer (score 0):

1. your first line of input hasn't been used.
2. in the for loop, count should be start from 0.
3. it seems the declaration of starcount should be put in the while loop rather than in the for loop. So it can count the the number of *.